# Calculating $\partial_t|f(t,z)|^2$ with $t\in\mathbb R$, $z\in\mathbb C$ and $f(t,z)\in\mathbb C$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R\times\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be differentiable. What is the derivative of $|f(t,z)|^2$ w.r.t. $t\in\mathbb R$, i.e. how do you calculate $\partial_t |f(t,z)|^2$?

I've tried to use $|f(t,z)|^2=\Re(f(t,z))^2+\Im(f(t,z))^2$ and hence $\partial_t |f(t,z)|^2=2\Re(f(t,z))\partial_tf(t,z)+2\Im(f(t,z))\partial_tf(t,z)$ which doesn't seem to be right since it's complex valued now. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $|f(t,z)|^2=f(t,z)\overline{f(t,z)}$.

Hence :

$$\partial_t|f(t,z)|^2=\overline{f(t,z)}\partial_tf(t,z)+f(t,z)\partial_t\overline{f(t,z)}.$$

But :

$$\partial_t\overline{f(t,z)}=\overline{\partial_tf(t,z)}.$$

Finally :

$$\partial_t|f(t,z)|^2= 2\Re\left( \overline{f(t,z)}\partial_tf(t,z)\right).$$

PS : not a very convenient formula, but I doubt one can do better without more assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $\partial_t\Re(f(t,z))^2=2\Re(f(t,z)) \cdot \partial_t \Re(f(t,z)) = 2\Re(f(t,z)) \cdot \Re(\partial_t f(t,z))$, so

$$\partial_t |f(t,z)|^2=2\Re(f(t,z)) \cdot \Re(\partial_t f(t,z))+2\Im(f(t,z)) \cdot \Im(\partial_t f(t,z))$$